# VS 2017 not discovering tests on .NET Core

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, test-explorer

can anyone help me get VS2017 to work with .NET Core test projects?

I tried creating both MSTest and xUnit unit test projects for .NET Core from the VS 2017 templates. Neither of them works in the test explorer (not discovered), however running `dotnet test` from the project folder works fine.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new project in VS 2017
2. Choose either the `Unit Test Project (.NET Core)` or `xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)` template
3. Implement some arbitrary unit test
4. Build the solution
5. Go to the text explorer and try to `Run All`

At this point the Output window should tell you that 0 test were discovered

`.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If I tried to create a MSTest unit test project from the template that targets .NET Framework (full, not .NET Core), it worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834871/cant-get-xunit-tests-working-with-visual-studio-2017-rc has helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: That actually worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Tests not discovered in Visual Studio 2017](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861930/unit-tests-not-discovered-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the end, the problem was solved by changing my system `PATH` env. variable from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` to `C:\Progra~1\dotnet\`, as answered in [Can't get XUnit tests working with Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834871/cant-get-xunit-tests-working-with-visual-studio-2017-rc)

Thanks to Alexey for suggesting it in the comments :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm running VS2017 Pro 15.1 and this was the only thing that fixed me.

Answer (score 7):

I think I experienced same behavior. Try to build your solution so that VS can discover your tests. Otherwise please share you tests csproj file to ensure you reference correct packages. Mine is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**UPDATE:** I have played around a bit and it looks like VS cannot find the tests without `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`

**UPDATE 2:** Try also add following to csproj as I see VS adds in in some cases.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Service Include="{82a7f48d-3b50-4b1e-b82e-3ada8210c358}" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I didn't mention it but I did build, building does not help unfortunately. I edited my post with my `.csproj` file. The only difference from yours is the `OutputType` tag there. I tried adding it but no difference at all.

Comment: @valorl try add `OutputType` and rebuild.

Comment: So I restarted my PC, made a clean solution with a clean xunit test project, added the `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`, rebuilt and tried to `Run All`. No success... even had VS running as admin. I'll try to reinstall maybe it'll help

Comment: No success even after I have reinstalled... My VS version is `Community 2017, VisualStudio/15.0.0-RTW+26228.4`

Comment: If it helps, event when adding the `OutputType` line, I don't see any `.exe` file in `bin\debug\netcoreapp1.1`

Comment: @valorl, I see glitches in VS, but if I build/clean/rebuild project several time VS can eventually discover it. Try also add `ItemGroup` that I posted in second update to see if it hepls.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help more. Please post a solution when you have it. Actually, try remove old .NET Core SDKs if you have those installed. Just a guess,  because I removed them before installing VS 2017.

Comment: If you go to the command line and type "dotnet --version" what does it say?

Comment: @Taylor It says `1.0.0`

Answer (score 5):

I hit this issue with VS 2017 not discovering MSTest unit tests on .NET Core.

The Tests output only reported that it had discovered zero tests.

On running `dotnet test MyProject.csproj -t` in a command prompt, it advised that I did not have the correct .NET Core runtime installed to match the project's RuntimeFrameworkVersion.

Installing the latest VS 2017 update and .NET Core runtime resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks DGreen. I also had an issue with VS 2017 discovering unit tests. While I had the correct framework referenced, your mention of the above command helped me discover that I did not have the unit test class access modifier set to public!

Comment: Thanks, I ran the command and got a warning that test class is nor marked as public, I added public keyword and now I can see my test.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I resolved it by installing the "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" package from nuget.

Comment: I added the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk and it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: I came here to share the exact same thing. I had one project among several in a solution that mysteriously just wouldn't show the tests. In the end, this is what solved it. So +1 from me.

Comment: This worked for me when my tests stopped showing up after switching my project from .NET Framework v4.6.1 to .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after migration from `project.json` to `csproj`. 
And resolved it by removing `net451` target framework and leave only `netcoreapp1.1`. Now it's works perfect and discover every time.

Of course if you need many framework targets you shouldn't do it, just use CLI to test them...

Answer (score 0):

It may due to inconsistent project settings for Processor Architecture. The Test project target must match the test default Processor Architecture.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47454276/2700303

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and it was remedied by ensuring my project and test project had the same target framework version in the .csproj file

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you don't have **mixed PackageReference versions** in the *.csproj files when having multiple test projects and the same output directory and also **update the packages of test project** especially MSTest.TestAdapter as well as MSTest.TestFramework

Answer (score 0):

Note for testing with SpecFlow.
If your solution has more projects you must include the package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" reference in each *.csproj